# Changing a record value before save in Suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to do something crazy simple, but can't figure out what is wrong with this code.  On a vendor record, upon the user clicking "save," I want a checkbox on the vendor record unchecked.  I can then run a regular report of vendors that have been modified that I haven't reviewed.  Here's the code I've tried:

```
/**
@NApiVersion 2.0
@NScriptType UserEventScript
@NModuleScope Public
*/

define(['N/record'], function (cr) {

function beforeSubmit() {

var myRecord = cr.currentRecord;

    myRecord.setValue({fieldId: 'custentitypmv_vendorreviewcomplete', value: false});
}

return {
    beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scriptContext to fetch the current record.

```
function beforeSubmit(scriptContext) {
   var myRecord = scriptContext.newRecord;
}
```

We use 'newRecord' in case of User Events and 'currentRecord' in case of ClientbScripts.

Follow the code below

```
/**
@NApiVersion 2.0
@NScriptType UserEventScript
@NModuleScope Public
*/

define(['N/record'], function (cr) {

function beforeSubmit(scriptContext) {

    var myRecord = scriptContext.newRecord;

    myRecord.setValue({fieldId: 'custentitypmv_vendorreviewcomplete', value: false});
}

return {
    beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
};
```

If this doesn't work, try using *afterSubmit* instead of *beforeSubmit*. Let me know in case of issues in the comments below.